# Resources packs are missing from the DLC page in Dead Space 3. How can I spend my ration seals?

Tags: steam, pc, dead-space-3

As you know, the game has a mechanism that allows you to earn ration seals. These seals can then be used to buy resources packs from within the game, which give the player with some resources and some "MK-V" parts to upgrade your weapons. The advantage being that the "MK-V" parts, unlike their normal counterparts, have extra stats bonus.

[image: A screenshot depicting the DLC store in the game. The resource packs tab is being selected, with only one product available: "Ultra Weapon and Resource Pack". That back can be bought for €1.99 or 30 ration seals. The description is partly visible, saying: "Even the odds with an Ultra Weapon and Resource Pack. Each pack is guaranteed to contain one MK-V Supercharged weapon part, with a 50% chance at a..."]

However, many PC players (both on Steam and off Steam) have experienced problems with the ration seals: they can't spend them.

They're supposed to be purchasable with real money or with ration seals. But for some reasons, for many players, the ration seals don't appear among the list of DLCs anymore.

Is there a way to fix this issue and spend ration seals to purchase resources packs as intended?

Comment: For what it's worth, I resorted to cheat engine to "trade" my resources packs into MK-V parts after the proposed solution no longed worked.. But I would discourage you of trying if you don't understand the implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 6th September 2022:** According to [this post](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Dead-Space-Games/PC-BUG-REPORT-Cannot-spend-Ration-Seals/m-p/11192185#M16659), the following solution doesn't work anymore, so ration seals can no longer be spent.

> I just now tested this, and it looks like my solution no longer works. Might be that they decided to remove it completely, or their related servers are down/broken.

## **Old post:**

---

**TL;DR:** You need a computer with Windows 8.1 or higher in order to perform the solution below. After you're done, you can keep playing on whatever operating system you usually use.

---

While I was searching up some information, I stumbled on some reasons as to why it might be happening:

- The first one some people were bringing up was the fact that the game needs to connect to some remote server for the ration seals purchase to work. However, since the server was shutdown (they believe it was when Visceral Games died, the video game developer studio owned by Electronic Arts that worked on Dead Space).
- The second hypothesis is the fact that it might be region locked. Some people who bought the game on Origin (before it was available on Steam) pointed out how they were able to buy resources packs with ration seals after using a VPN to set their location to the United States. Some of them commented how neither living in Europe nor in Canada allowed them to access it until using the VPN.
- The third one I noticed is because I bought the game on Steam. Whenever I tried to boot the game, a banner was displaying on Origin, saying: "The Origin store is currently disabled because it was launched from another application". Trying to boot the game on Origin alone would boot it through Steam. Trying to boot the game on Steam alone would boot it through Origin. And trying to shut down both Steam and Origin, then booting the desktop icon, would launch both Origin and Steam. In all scenarios, the message keeps appearing and the resources packs are not available in the DLC page.

[Some users suggested some solutions over there on EA forums](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Dead-Space-Games/PC-BUG-REPORT-Cannot-spend-Ration-Seals/m-p/10693233/highlight/true#M16529), one of which worked for me.

**Before doing the solution**, make sure to:

1. Have a computer with Windows 8.1 or higher available for the procedure. Mine is running on Windows 7, so I borrowed a computer with Windows 10 just to do it.
2. Install the game through Steam/Origin on the computer with Windows 8.1 or higher.
3. Boot the game to have all the latest save files on the computer.

After making sure you have the game installed with all your saves on a computer with Windows 8.1 or higher, do the following:

1. Within Origin, go to your application settings and uncheck the option to launch on boot.
2. Exit Origin entirely (closing the window alone won't do; you have to right click on the process in the bottom right and exit).
3. Go to the install folder of Dead Space 3 then create a shortcut for the game on the desktop. Creating a shortcut through Steam won't work, as it will try to boot the game through Origin.
4. Download and install the EA Beta App through this link: https://www.ea.com/ea-app-beta. If your computer is running on Windows 7, you won't be able to install it.
5. Once the installation is done, boot EA Beta App and login using your Origin credentials.
6. While EA Beta App is running in background, use the shortcut you created on your desktop to launch the game. If you created a Steam shortcut, Origin will tell you that it can't boot while EA Beta App is running. If you created a desktop shortcut through the installation folder of Dead Space 3, it will boot through EA Beta App.
7. Load your saves. If your saves are missing because you borrowed someone else's computer, you forgot to follow the "**Before doing the solution**" steps. You need to shut down EA Beta App, boot Origin, launch the game normally. Origin will ask you to choose between the local saves and the cloud saves. Pick the cloud saves to retrieve your remote saves. Then close Origin and repeat from step 5.
8. Load a game and get to a Bench (in the Weapon Crafting Arena for example).
9. Open the DLC store. You can now spend 30 ration seals on a resource pack. Make sure you avoid pressing Enter or clicking on Purchase (with real money), or else your game will be stuck trying to load forever.
10. Once done, you can save your game, close EA Beta App, boot Origin and boot the game to synchronise your saves. Then you came resume playing normally.